Question on Continuum Mechanics: How does Eulerian derivatives of $f$ and Lagrangian derivatives of $f$ different?
Consider a particle $M$ occupying the position $\vec{a}$ at time $t = 0$ and the position $\vec{x}$ at time $t$. A function $f = f(M, t)$ associated with a particle $M$ (e.g., its velocity, acceleration, or other physical quantities to be defined subsequently) can be represented in two different ways during the motion:
$$
f(M, t) = g(\vec{a}, t) \quad \text{or} \quad f(M, t) = h(\vec{x}, t),
$$
where $\vec{x} = \Phi(\vec{a}, t)$; that is to say
$$
h(\Phi(\vec{a}, t), t) = g(\vec{a}, t).
$$
$\textbf{Definition 1.5.}$
1.$ \textit{The Eulerian derivatives of $f$ are the quantities}$
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}(\vec{x}, t), \quad \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(\vec{x}, t).
$$
2. $\textit{The Lagrangian derivatives of $f$ are the quantities}$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial a_i}(\vec{a}, t), \quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(\vec{a}, t).
$$
In mechanical engineering the derivative $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)(\vec{a}, t)$ is denoted $ \frac{dh}{dt}$ or $ \frac{Dh}{Dt}$ (or $ \frac{df}{dt}$ or $ \frac{Df}{Dt}$) and is sometimes called the total derivative of $f$.
My doubt:-

How does Eulerian derivatives of $f$ and Lagrangian derivatives of $f$
different?

My attempt:-
I can see that in Eulerian derivative parial derivatives or total derivatives are evaluated at $(\vec x, t).$ But in the Lagrangian derivatives are evaluated at $(\vec a, t).$  What does that mean physically? could you explain?
